# Use BLAS library in C Mex-File

Tags: c, matlab, mex, blas

I am trying to use the BLAS library for my C-Mex-Code to analyze performance differences with and without BLAS. However, I couldn't figure out how to use BLAS correctly without getting compile errors/warnings (and eventually Matlab Crashes).

Below is a sample code where I would like to calculate a vector product using the ddot()-function of Blas ( https://software.intel.com/de-de/node/468398#D4E53C70-D8FA-4095-A800-4203CAFE64FE ):

```
  #include <mex.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <blas.h>

  void TestBlas(double *L, double *R, mwSize n)
  {

      int one = 1;
      double sum = ddot(&n,L,&one,L,&one);

      //Output Matrix R not defined, just for test purposes...

  } 

  void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
  {
      double *inMatrix;               /* 1xN input matrix */
      size_t ncols;                   /* size of matrix */
      long *ncolsPr;                  /* output matrix */
      double *outMatrix;              /* output matrix */

      inMatrix = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
      ncols = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

      /* create the output matrix */
      plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,(mwSize)ncols,mxREAL);
      outMatrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

      TestBlas(inMatrix,outMatrix,(mwSize)ncols);
  }
```

The compiler warnings I receive are:

```
 >> mex -largeArrayDims TestBlas.c -lmwblas
  Building with 'Xcode with Clang'.
  /Users/jhess/Dropbox/Uni/E-Technik Master/Forschungspraxis Machine Learning/Matlab/TestBlas.c:9:23: warning: passing 'mwSize *' (aka 'unsigned long *') to parameter of type 'const ptrdiff_t *' (aka 'const long *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
      double sum = ddot(&n,L,&one,L,&one);
                        ^~
  /Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/extern/include/blas.h:559:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'n' here
      const ptrdiff_t *n,
                       ^
  /Users/jhess/Dropbox/Uni/E-Technik Master/Forschungspraxis Machine Learning/Matlab/TestBlas.c:9:28: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int *' to parameter of type 'const ptrdiff_t *' (aka 'const long *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      double sum = ddot(&n,L,&one,L,&one);
                             ^~~~
  /Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/extern/include/blas.h:561:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'incx' here
      const ptrdiff_t *incx,
                       ^
  /Users/jhess/Dropbox/Uni/E-Technik Master/Forschungspraxis Machine Learning/Matlab/TestBlas.c:9:35: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int *' to parameter of type 'const ptrdiff_t *' (aka 'const long *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      double sum = ddot(&n,L,&one,L,&one);
                                    ^~~~
  /Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/extern/include/blas.h:563:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'incy' here
      const ptrdiff_t *incy
                       ^
  3 warnings generated.

  MEX completed successfully.
```

It seems to be something like I am passing wrong variable-types (or pointer-types?) to the BLAS-function but I just couldn't figure out how to fix it. Can somebody have a look please?
Many thanks!

Comment: As the warning says: `ddot` expects `integer n`, while you give it `mwSize n`. That's a no-no. I've had several difficulties from such problems: always define the proper local variables which you pass to the BLAS/LAPACK routines, and do the type cast on them. Try using `int n` in your `TestBlas` function, and correspondingly casting `size_t` to `int` when calling it.

Comment: [This link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/227890-wrong-result-when-using-blas-dot-product-routine-ddot-from-a-mex-file#comment_296263) should also be very helpful: "*mwSignedIndex is usually what is recommended for the integer arguments of BLAS and LAPACK functions for the libraries that MATLAB ships with ... at least that is what is used in the example code. I haven't scanned through the header files to see if this always reduces to ptrdiff_t or not.*". This explains the rest of your warnings, which should indeed cause problems (`int` vs `long`).

Comment: I added an answer based on my best guess. Please check it out, as I'm admittedly unsure whether it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my suspicion is correct, you just have to define the proper types of the integers involved in your code:

```
  #include <mex.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <blas.h>

  void TestBlas(double *L, double *R, mwSignedIndex n) //changed
  {

      mwSignedIndex one = 1; //changed
      double sum = ddot(&n,L,&one,L,&one);

      //Output Matrix R not defined, just for test purposes...

  } 

  void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
  {
      double *inMatrix;               /* 1xN input matrix */
      size_t ncols;                   /* size of matrix */
      long *ncolsPr;                  /* output matrix */
      double *outMatrix;              /* output matrix */

      inMatrix = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
      ncols = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

      /* create the output matrix */
      plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mwSize)1,(mwSize)ncols,mxREAL); //changed
      outMatrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

      TestBlas(inMatrix,outMatrix,(mwSignedIndex)ncols); //changed
  }
```

In my experience you have to be especially careful with literal constants appearing in the function calls, so note the cast of `1` to `(mwSize)`, which `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` expects.

Comment: This was a very comprehensive and helpful answer, thanks again!

Comment: @user3116232 I'm glad I could help. Just to be clear: did this indeed solve your problem?:)

Comment: Yes, because I was really confused by the file types that BLAS wanted. I still am but now I know how to adapt my code. Understanding comes on the go I guess ;)